# Using PnP Powershell, retreive a document's path

Tags: pnp-powershell

I'm using PnP Powershell (which I'm new to) and I wish to find the URL of a document in a document library. The following returns Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectPathIdentity rather than an actual value. Here's my code:

```
$url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/test"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $url –Credentials (Get-Credential $userCredential)
$web = Get-PnPWeb

$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$libs = Get-PnPList | Where{$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101} 

foreach($lib in $libs)

{

$libitems = Get-PnPListItem -List $lib -Fields "FileLeafRef"

foreach($libitem in $libitems)

{

    if({$_.Name -match ".doc*"}) 

    {

        write-host "lib path... "$libitem.Path

     }

 }

}
```

The output is:

lib path...  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectPathIdentity
followed by the Id, Title and Unique Id of all library items in the library.

Any thoughts? I was expecting the Path of the list item to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$libitem["FileRef"]`.

So, modify your inner `foreach` loop as below:

```
foreach($libitem in $libitems)
{
    if({$_.Name -match ".doc*"}) 
    {
        write-host "lib path... " $libitem["FileRef"]
    }
}
```

It gives you the server-relative path of the file.

Also,if you just want the file name, use `$libitem["FileLeafRef"]`